# TS18048: variable is possibly undefined although being checked

Tags: typescript, webpack

```
interface Result {
  a: Record<string, string>;
  b: string;
  c: string
}

const func = async (): Promise < Result > => {
  // some logic
  return {
    a: {
        aa: 'aa',
      bb: 'bb',
      cc: 'cc'
    },
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
  };
}

const func2 = async (val: string): Promise < string > => {
  // some logic
  return `${val}-string`;
}

(async () => {
  let result: Result | undefined;

  await func().then(response => (result = response));

  if (!result) {
    return;
  }

    const { aa } = result.a;
  console.log(aa);

  (async () => {
    const { bb } = result.a; // TS18048: 'result' is possibly 'undefined'
  
    await func2(bb).then(response => console.log(response));
  })();
})();
```

In the above code, the first `console.log` works as expected ("aa"), but I cannot use the `result` variable inside the following function (`func2`) because of the following error:
`TS18048: 'result' is possibly 'undefined'.`

What is the difference? Why was I able to use the deconstruct variable `aa` outside the last function, and while trying to deconstruct the result inside the last function, I'm getting this error?

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "webpack/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "wrapper",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:stage": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.stage.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
    "@types/google-publisher-tag": "1.20220926.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.48.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.48.0",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.2",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.2",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.4",
    "webpack": "5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get errors way before that point. The `func()` function doesn't return it's declared return type.

Comment: @MikeS. sorry, I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when the compiler is performing nullability analysis in the body of a lambda, there's very little it can assume about the content of any captured variables.

Consider this slight variant of your method:

```
const func2 = async (val: string): Promise < string > => {
  // some logic
  return `${val}-string`;
}

(async () => {
  let result: Result | undefined;

  await func().then(response => (result = response));

  if (!result) {
    return;
  }

    const { aa } = result.a;
  console.log(aa);

  const f = (async () => {
    const { bb } = result.a; // TS18048: 'result' is possibly 'undefined'
  
    await func2(bb).then(response => console.log(response));
  });
  f();
})();
```

When compiling `f`, all it knows is that `result` is captured. It *cannot* use any control flow logic from before the definition of `f` to "know" that `result` is not `undefined`.

It doesn't attempt to reason about *future* code it's not compiling yet. It doesn't know (as we humans do) that a) `f` is invoked immediately and b) that `f` will not be stored anywhere such that it can be invoked later.

We as humans can see an easy way that `result` could become undefined between the lambda being compiled and it being invoked:

```
  const f = (async () => {
    const { bb } = result.a; // TS18048: 'result' is possibly 'undefined'
  
    await func2(bb).then(response => console.log(response));
  });
  result = undefined;
  f();
```

You could argue that immediately invoked lambdas that aren't captured in explicit variables could be a special case since we then know that they are invoked exactly once in the same control flow state as before the lambda is defined.

But that would still require looking ahead beyond the body of a lambda (to know that it's immediately invoked) and now you have two different "flavours" of nullability analysis under which lambda bodies might be analysed.

You know that `result` isn't `undefined` in your usage. Use the tools already at your disposal to inform the compiler of that fact that it isn't designed to deduce for itself.